# How to play midi files in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, midi

I have windows 8. How to play midi files in it?

I have tried various software products which claim that they enable playing midi in windows 8. But none really worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To play MIDI files you need to have a MIDI out device available on your system.

On Windows XP, they were two MIDI out devices:
 - MIDIMapper (a special MIDI out device bundled with XP), installed as MIDI out device #0, and
 - Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth (MGWS), a (low quality) software wave synth, installed as MIDI out device #1.

Users were able to configure their preferred MIDI out device, and this setting was used by MIDIMapper.

On Windows Vista / 7, it was the same as above, but MIDIMapper configuration disappeared from control panel (registry settings were still available, so some third party tools were released as workaround).

On Windows 8, the MIDIMapper device (#0) has been completely removed so MIDI softwares are now *required* to select a specific device (no selection still means #0).
I wrote "required" because, worst of all, MGWS is now installed with some sort of "dynamic" ID: #0 out of the box, but it becomes #1 if you install another one (like a MIDI software or an USB MIDI device). I suppose device numbering is done alphabetically, but I can't confirm it.

The only way to select a specific device is use a MIDI software with a configuration option to select a device, for example [VirtualMidiSynth](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth) (I am not endorsed in any way with this editor).